# AWS lambda create cloudformation stack using java

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a cloudformation stack using java. I have created before using python, but trying to convert that to java

```
import boto3
import time

datetime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
stackname = 'abc'
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.create_stack(
  StackName= (stackname+ '-' + datetime),
  TemplateURL='https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc/xyz.json',
  Parameters=[
    {
        'ParameterKey': 'Environment',
        'ParameterValue': 'dev',
        'UsePreviousValue': False
    }
  ]
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
            return(response)
```

Comment: What problems are you having with the Java SDK?  It looks like [createStack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudformation/AmazonCloudFormation.html#createStack-com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.model.CreateStackRequest-) is the Java version.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Java. I havn't use Lambda much and still trying to do hello world examples with Java and Lambda

Comment: It's almost the same, you just need to adapt to a different language...This may help you to get started: [CreateStack Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=march4-master/lib/1.7.2/samples/AwsCloudFormation/CloudFormationSample.java)

Comment: Hi Tom, please add your response as answer and I will accept it. that is awesome stuff you have put together. Thanks a ton